# My App for Windows Phone 8.1 not install in real phones

Tags: apps, error

I developed an App for Gym (app in portuguese language - target brazilian users) and this app does not install from Windows phone Store in any device that I had tested.

The errors are not easy to identify the problem in my App.

My app is: [Treino da Academia](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/store/apps/treino-da-academia/9nblggh6gs76)

Somebody help me? :'(

Comment: This question is about software development, which should be asked on Stack Overflow. However, there's no way you're going to get an answer there at this point. You'll need to include, at the very least, the exact error code.

Answer (score 1):

The phone you used to test, needs to registered for developing purpose , so that you can install apps outside of Windows Phone Store.

- So unregister the phone you tested your app on, and try to install again from Phone Store.